# How do I control servos using Processing code and an Arduino UNO Board?

Tags: arduino, processing, communication, servo

I'm not a code writer (though I'm quite familiar with [LabVIEW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LabVIEW)). My background is in laser and optical system design and development.

Currently, I'm trying to integrate servos into an optical component used in a long range atmosphere mapping [Lidar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lidar).  The optical component, refereed to as a TR-Swich, is critical in maintaining the alignment between the *transmitted laser* pulse stream and back-scattered *return* light.  In order to ensure long-term alignment and compensate for optical mount thermal and shock drift, the servos - connected to optical mount pitch and yaw actuators - will allow our customers to adjust the TR-Swich as needed and thereby maintain optimum signal returns.

Due to a variety of constraints (time, space, ease of integration into existing hardware, etc.), I'm hoping to use servos, which are small and reliable and can be easily controlled using an Arduino Uno board.  I've already proven that they work quite well to move and set the position of the actuators; now I'm trying to get the GUI interface working...which hopefully is where all of you come in...

Since I'm new to Arduino board code (and the related Processing code), I snooped around and found code published on hackster.io (back in 2020) - which is close to what I'm looking for.  The code was written by engineerkid (his hackster user name).

I copied his code for both the Arduino board and the Processing GUI, but I haven't been able to get it to work. I reached out to him (through hackster), but I haven't received a reply.  The message I sent him was,

> Hi Enginnerkid,
>
> First, I want to thank you for posting the example! It's very close to what I ultimately need for adjusting optical mounts using servos. I copied your code for both the Arduino and Processing sketches and it's close to working, but something isn't quite right.
>
> The servo (practically identical to what you're using in your example) moves to the center position and the display based on the mouse position using the Processing code work just fine. Unfortunately, the servo doesn't respond to the mouse movements. As a heads up, currently I'm only using one servo - are two servos required in order for the code to work?
>
> Going on this premise, I deleted the code related to one of the servos, but still wasn't able to achieve any movement. I did some browsing regarding communication problems between Arduino and Processing code and found the following comment (which might be relevant), "
>
> The serial monitor in Arduino is like a separate terminal program so it and your Processing sketch are competing for the same serial connection to the Arduino." Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated! Thanks! Steve

His Arduino code is:

```
#include <Servo.h>
char tiltChannel=0, panChannel=1;
Servo servoTilt, servoPan;
char serialChar=0;


void setup()
{
  servoTilt.attach(9);  // The Tilt servo is attached to pin 9.
  servoPan.attach(10);  // The Pan servo is attached to pin 10.
  servoTilt.write(90);  // Initially put the servos both
  servoPan.write(90);   // at 90 degrees.
  Serial.begin(57600);  // Set up a serial connection for 57,600 bit/s.
}

void loop()
{
  while(Serial.available() <=0);  //Wait for a character on the serial port.
  serialChar = Serial.read();     //Copy the character from the serial port to the variable
  if(serialChar == tiltChannel){  //Check to see if the character is the servo ID for the tilt servo
    while(Serial.available() <=0);  //Wait for the second command byte from the serial port.
    servoTilt.write(Serial.read());  //Set the tilt servo position to the value of the second command byte received on the serial port
  }
  else if(serialChar == panChannel){ //Check to see if the initial serial character was the servo ID for the pan servo.
    while(Serial.available() <= 0);  //Wait for the second command byte from the serial port.
    servoPan.write(Serial.read());   //Set the pan servo position to the value of the second command byte received from the serial port.
  }
  //If the character is not the pan or tilt servo ID, it is ignored.
}
```

His Processing code is:

```
import processing.serial.*;
Serial port; // The serial port we will be using
int xpos=90; // set x servo's value to mid point (0-180)
int ypos=90; // set y servo's value to mid point (0-180)

void setup()
{
  size(360, 360);
  frameRate(100);
  String arduinoPort = Serial.list()[0];
  port = new Serial(this, arduinoPort, 57600);
}

void draw()
{
  fill(175);
  rect(0,0,360,360);
  fill(255,0,0); //rgb value so RED
  rect(180, 175, mouseX-180, 10); //xpos, ypos, width, height
  fill(0,255,0); // and GREEN
  rect(175, 180, 10, mouseY-180);
  update(mouseX, mouseY);
}

void update(int x, int y)
{
  //Calculate servo position from mouseX
  xpos= x/2;
  ypos = y/2;
  //Output the servo position ( from 0 to 180)
  port.write(xpos+"x");
  port.write(ypos+"y");
}
```

If you would like to look at his code, and the really cool example he set up, the page is:

*[Servo Motor Control Using Arduino and Processing](https://www.hackster.io/engineerkid/servo-motor-control-using-arduino-and-processing-af8225#team)*

As mentioned above, I simplified the code by removing the pan servo control, but still wasn't able to get any response from the servo using the tilt portion of the code.  It does appear to be related to a communication bottleneck, I'm just not sure what small snip-it of code needs to be added to prevent the conflict.

By the way, one indication that the communication is at fault is the LED serial com lights on the Arduino board. Prior to using (or trying to use the Processing GUI), I copied published code for moving a servo just with the Arduino code and was able to position the servo at any desired angle (form 0 to 180 degrees).

I noticed that with each upload of the code (which would set the servo to any chosen hard coded angle value), the LEDs would flicker and toggle back and forth as the new code uploaded.  Now with the GUI, only one LED stays on continuously... which is probably not a good sign...

Answer (score 0):

The Java code does not send what your Arduino sketch expects (or vice versa).

You're reading a single control character and compare it with one of two allowed values:

```
 serialChar = Serial.read();
 if(serialChar == tiltChannel){
```

I suggest to change at the Arduino side

```
char tiltChannel='x', panChannel='y';
```

And to modify the Java side to

```
port.write("x");
port.write(xpos);
```

The same for the other servo, too.

And make sure each Java `port.write` sends a single byte only.

Comment: Wow! I implemented your code suggestions and everything now works! Many Thanks!!

Comment: You might notify Engineerkid that his project isn't completely foolproof, and mark this one as "solution". Thanks for the feedback, BTW,

Comment: Hi datafiddler,

Comment: Hi datafiddler...good idea... I just posted a comment on his example page related to the changes you suggested.  Hopefully, the input will be helpful to all others referring to and using the design.  Thanks again for all your help! By the way, once this code was working, I saved a copy and created a GUI that uses buttons (on the screen) to set specific angular movements of each servo.  Now, I can dial in, optimize and set the alignment of each optical mount with extreme precision! Now, my only problem is getting the Arduino code running on the National Instrument (NI) computer...